# For loops goes on forever

Tags: c++, for-loop

Somehow, when I run this program, it'll go on forever even though I wrote it in a way that makes it stop when i reaches 10. Please help.

```
double i;
for(i = 0; i != 10; i+= 0.1){
    printf("%.1f\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Print `i` with more decimals and see what's happening.

Comment: apply condition `i <=10.0` it will solve your problem...

Comment: "Apply conditiion foo" without explaining why is a terrible answer.  it's only a slightly better comment.

Comment: decimal points need to be cared

Comment: The point is (no pun intended) by using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken I now know that technically if you push it out enough decimal places it will never actually = 10.

Comment: [This is almost the exact same issue](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FLP30-C.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters).  Floating point is not exact.  Adding `0.1` does not guarantee all of those sums will give you exactly 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.1 cannot be represented accurately as `double`.

A quick fix is to change the loop condition into `i < 10`.

Otherwise use loop variable of an integer type, a fixed precision float, or whatever else.

Note, however, that with other decimal increments, notably the negative powers of 2 (0.5, 0.25, etc.), it might work, provided the overall iteration count is not too high.

Comment: It's useful to point out that the fraction 1/10 can't be represented in binary for the same reason that the fraction 1/3 can't be represented in decimal. 1/10 in binary repeats forever: 0.000110011001100110011.... which means that decimal 0.1 doesn't have an exact representation in the binary number system.